# SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h not found while working with Stripe

Tags: ios

I am currently working on a project where i am using the Stripe package for implementing PaymentGateWay from my project.I have used UnitTesting for this project(Automatically imports SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h). But while compiling the project

```
//
//  PKCardCVCTest.h
//  PKPayment Example
//
//  Created by Alex MacCaw on 2/6/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Stripe. All rights reserved.
//

#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>

@interface PKCardCVCTest : SenTestCase

@end
```

this PKCardCVCTest class causing the error showing that SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h file not found.
Can any body help me please...

Answer (score 0):

Make shure the Framework Search Paths's for your Test class (PKCardCVCTest) are correctly set. If you use XCode later than 4.5 the path should be setted in "". Please consider this blog article: http://blog.drunknbass.com/post/32310268995/if-you-upgraded-to-xcode-4-5-recently-and-your